# function for random password generate

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want a function that will generate random password. I will give function
four parameter as how many number that password will contain, how many number of upper case that password will contain, how, many number of lower case that password will contain and how many special characters that password will contain and the return password will be mixture of those input parameters.

```sql
create or replace function(
  number_of_digits         in number,
  no_of_special_characters in number,
  no_of_lower              in number,
  no_of_upper              in number
) return varchar2
as
  password
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [MRE] including: **YOUR** attempt at a solution; sample input that would be passed into the function; the expected output from the function for those inputs; and the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution. StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service; **YOU** need to put the initial effort and attempt a solution and then we can help with debugging.

Comment: now check my question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
create function generate_password(
  no_of_digits             in number,
  no_of_special_characters in number,
  no_of_lower              in number,
  no_of_upper              in number
) return varchar2
AS
  password VARCHAR2(4000);
  digits   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(10) := '0123456789';
  lower    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(26) := 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  upper    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(26) := 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  special  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(32) := '!"£$%^&*()-_=+{}[]<>,.\|/?;:''@#';
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(letter, NULL) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
  INTO   password
  FROM   (
    SELECT SUBSTR(
             digits,
             FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, LENGTH(digits) + 1)),
             1
           ) AS letter
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= no_of_digits
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTR(
             lower,
             FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, LENGTH(lower) + 1)),
             1
           ) AS letter
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= no_of_lower
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTR(
             upper,
             FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, LENGTH(upper) + 1)),
             1
           ) AS letter
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= no_of_upper
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTR(
             special,
             FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, LENGTH(special) + 1)),
             1
           ) AS letter
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= no_of_special_characters
  );
  
  RETURN password;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT generate_password(5,3,4,4)
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

May randomly output:

> | GENERATE_PASSWORD(5,3,4,4) |
> | --- |
> | 1>9zq$Qw%E16fJ8B |
> | J$rYKtH2813vt]7} |
> | fRh2bS8U0.55]Vs= |
> | {N6Zd£Or8e5u5R|4 |
> | H9c:_5VFmyZ58't7 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0697d841732539c33e02e11fd21dd866)*

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `dbms_random.string('P', length)`. The `P` parameter, according to Oracle's documentation prints all printable characters.

Here's an example:

```
select replace(dbms_random.string('P', 10), ' ', 'x') str from dual;
```

I used replace in this example, to eliminate the possibility of a space, since they're hard for users to comprehend at times.

Comment: The OP was asking for a function where you can pass in "how much number, special character, lowercase and uppercase characters that password will have".

Comment: check my question again

Comment: @MT0 In that case that's a different question and not as easy to solve. At least not within a query.

Comment: @Tilin You can look at the [original edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/914581cc-ddea-4102-beab-61d59f30e63c/view-source) of the question and that requirement was there from the start. The question is not different.

Comment: @MT0 Originally, I understood it as the length of the string.